# How to Setup/Verify method call with specified parameter

Tags: c#, moq

I need to test if method `GetKey(object target)` was called with specified parameter. I know that verification can be called like

```
processor.Verify(x => x.GetKey(It.Is<object>(y => y == target)));
```

but how should setup look?

```
processor.Setup(x => x.GetKey(It.Is<object>(y => y == target)));
```

or

```
processor.Setup(x => x.GetKey(It.IsAny<object>()));
```

What is the difference in these 2 setups? Does it really matter in this case?

The processor interface:

```
public interface ILayoutProcessor
{
    object GetKey(object target);
}
```

Comment: How does the complete signature of the method `GetKey` look like? It returns something? The two setups are different, the first one is specific for `target` where the second is for any `object`.

Comment: I know the difference between `It.Is` and `It.IsAny`. If I would like to use different `Callback` or `Return` base on parameter I would use `It.Is`, but in case when I do not even care about returned value can I use `It.IsAny` in `Setup` and `It.Is` in `Verify`?

Comment: Yes I think you can.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the specified parameter in the `Setup` or `Verify` method expression

```
processor.Setup(x => x.GetKey(target)).Verifiable();
```

and verify later

```
processor.Verify();
```

or

```
processor.Verify(x => x.GetKey(target), Times.AtLeastOnce);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
processor.Setup(x => x.GetKey(It.Is<object>(y => y == target)));
```

Is a setup for when the method is called with an object matching the specified condition.

```
processor.Setup(x => x.GetKey(It.IsAny<object>()));
```

Is a setup that will match any object argument.

In your case, where you want to only verify that the method was called with a certain argument, it does not matter which setup you use. In fact, if the return value of your function is not used, you don't even need a setup to be able to verify. However in your case I assume you do since you mention `Callback` and `Returns` in the comments.

Note that you can shorten your verification to simply:

```
processor.Verify(x => x.GetKey(target));
```